# Matplotlib graph is empty window

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a graph using Matplotlib however it just prints out an empty window. If I run my cursor through the window it shows the x and y values of the graph that is supposed to be there. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = [1,2,3]
y = [5,7,4]

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. How did you install matplotlib? What is your operating system?

Comment: probably with pip3 install matplotlib. I'm on MacOS Sierra

Comment: Hmm, I have a similar setup. Maybe try a different backend? This might also be a legit bug in which case the thing to do is report the issue on matplotlib’s github.

Comment: How do I use a different backend?

Comment: What's the version of matplotlib you are using? For a different backend, add `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` or any other name of a backend your system supports.